# Tell TypeScript to use the types of another module to current module with different name

Tags: typescript

I'm using a module (`dom-to-image`) that has Types (through Definitely Typed) but is unmantained, so I'm using a fork (called `dom-to-image-more`) of it with a few more updates.  However, the fork doesn't have types.

How can I tell TypeScript to use `dom-to-image`'s types but assign them to the other module? Since they're installed through `@types/dom-to-image` TypeSript automatically assigns them to that module (if I understand how it works correctly, I may now).

I can shut TS from complaining by creating a `.d.ts` file and adding `declare module "dom-to-image-more";`. But I'd like to maintain the original Types.

A simple solution is to copy-paste the types from the module into my `.d.ts`, but I'd prefer to reuse the original types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to install `@types/dom-to-image` under alias `@types/dom-to-image-more`:

```bash
yarn add -D @types/dom-to-image-more@npm:@types/dom-to-image
```

or

```bash
npm install --save-dev @types/dom-to-image-more@npm:@types/dom-to-image
```

In the `package.json` file it will be:

```json
"@types/dom-to-image-more": "npm:@types/dom-to-image"
```

And you can control versions as regular:

```json
"@types/dom-to-image-more": "npm:@types/dom-to-image@^2.6.3"
```